# CCK Date field not showing stored values in node edit form

Tags: entities, nodes

After moving a Drupal 6.x site to a new server, I've found that a CCK date field being used by multiple content types is not displaying the values that are stored in the database for the field OR the default value as defined under content management and date field when creating a new node. The field is just blank. For stored nodes, the values are still there when viewing the node, they just disappear when editing it.

I've found two similar issues, but both relate to multilingual support in Drupal 7:
 1. [Why some fields values are getting empty when editing a node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112148/why-some-fields-values-are-getting-empty-when-editing-a-node)
 2. https://www.drupal.org/node/1146056

ANSWER: I upgraded the Date API module to 6.x-2.10 and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you have the latest Date module version installed, 6.x-2.10. There is a similar issue in the module's queue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2230167). Run phpinfo() and see if Memcached is installed on your new server. Uninstalling the extension could possibly solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That link is very helpful. Can you say more about how Memcached might help? The only reference I see to it on the page you linked to is as something that needed to purged to get rid of the problem: " After purging php5-memcached, we haven't seen emptied-out CCK fields anymore." (https://www.drupal.org/node/2230167#comment-8649125). I'm not familiar with Memcached, so I'd welcome an education here.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the opposite. Did you find out if it's installed on your server? You can find more information about it on the manual ("memcached is a high-performance, distributed memory object caching system, generic in nature, but intended for use in speeding up dynamic web applications by alleviating database load.").

Comment: Memcached was not installed, but your assumption at the beginning did end up fixing my problem, because I checked the Date API module and it was an old dev version. I upgraded to 6.x-2.10 and the problem was fixed. Thanks!